# I'm creating a quiz game with 4 answers and I want to add score

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a quiz game with 4 answers and I want to add score. Every right answer is worth  50 points and wrong answers are -50 points. How do I do that?

```
- (IBAction)bpressed1:(id)sender {
    if ([self.answer isEqualToString:@"a"]) {

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"yes!"
                                                          message:@"+50."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];

        [message release];

        [self nextq];

    }else{

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"no!"
                                                          message:@"-50."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil]
        [message show];

        [message release];

        [self nextq];
    }
}
```

Comment: What on Earth language is this in?

Comment: This looks like Objective-C

Comment: xcode................

Comment: Xcode is not a language. Objective-C is.

Comment: yes you re right... any ideas how i can make the "score" ?thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can have an `@property (nonatomic) int score;` in your header file along with a UILabel to display the score. Whenever someone presses the correct answer, do `self.score+=50;` and set the label's text to the new score.

Comment: im a new thats why i need you help

Comment: And that's why I told you exactly what to do. If you don't know how to do at least that much, look up some tutorial on how to program in Objective-C.

Comment: something like scores = -50;
        self.score.text = [scores];

Comment: scoreno = scoreno +50;
        self.score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scoreno]; ok thanks i finaly with your help i figure it out. thanks guys